# QNetworkAccessManager from ThreadPool

Tags: multithreading, qt, threadpool, runnable, qnetworkaccessmanager

A very fundamental question. The documentation mentions that all methods in `QNetworkAccessManager` are reentrant. If so, is performing a `get()` method in a `QRunnable` without locks legal? My code would look something like this:

```
class MyClass: public QRunnable
{
    void run()
    {
        ...
        QNetworkAccessManager nam;
        QNetworkReply* reply =  name.get(request)    // No Read-write lock.
        ...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the Qt documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/threads-reentrancy.html):

> [...] a class is said to be *reentrant* if its member functions can [simultaneously] be
>   called safely from multiple threads, as long as each thread uses a *different* instance of
>   the class.

Since you're using a different instance each time (the one you create on the stack in `run()`), you're on the safe side.

Comment: If I had an instance of QNetworkAccessManager shared between different threads, Would the call to get still be valid from different threads ?? i.e if the QNetworkAccessManager instance is passed to the QRunnable at the time of its instantiation and its get method is called in run() like I mentioned above, would it still ensure no trouble ??

Comment: @de costa: no, it would blow up. You'd need a `QMutex` to serialise access to it, *but*: `QNetworkAccessManager` is a `QObject` and as such needs to be `moveToThread()`ed to safely call it, even with mutex protection (event handlers may be called on `QObject`s at basically any time). Since `QRunnable`s run on a thread that you can't predict from outside `QThreadPool`, and `moveToThread()` can only _push_ an object to, not _pull_ from another thread, you cannot use `QObject`s that in `QRunnable`s that were not created there (unless you internally synchronize them, ie. make them thread-safe).

Comment: In that case, how expensive would it be to create a QNetworkAccessManager on each individual QRunnable inside a ThreadPool ?? Is it considered a good practice ?? Other alternative but potentially undebuggable implementation is having a QObject in my QRunnable and implement signal/slot communication to the QNetworkAccessManager which was instantiated on the thread that created the QTHreadPool. Any suggestions ??

Comment: @de costo: It's what you're already doing in the OP. Regarding cost: `QNetworkAccessManager` is basically a parametrisable factory (as in Abstract Factory). If you don't need the parametrisibility (e.g., you don't want to extend it with additional supported protocols), creating it there and then should have minimal overhead. If you can't use it that way for one reason or another, just use it in the main thread, which is the slightly more idiomatic way. `QNetworkReply`s are `QIODevices` and support async operation with e.g. the `readyRead()` signal, so you don't need threads (load is IO bound).

Comment: @Marc Mutz: if we use more than one `QNetworkAccessManager` its difficult to set the cache and proxy settings for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

As a side note to this ,if you just want the GET request to be asynchronous, `QNetworkAccessManager` is already asynchronous (says so in the docs).