# Best way to share cookies within Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, cookies, qnetworkaccessmanager

I can use `QNetworkCookieJar` to retrieve, store and resend cookies of a `QNetworkManager`. Multiple `QNetworkAccessManager` instances can share a single `QNetworkCookieJar`.

So far I have used multiple `QNetworkAccessManager` instances, one per class (where I need to read):

1. So I could have a singleton `QNetworkCookieJar` shared across 1..n `QNetworkAccessManager` instances
2. Or is it better to have only a singleton `QNetworkAccessManager` with one Jar shared across all `QNetworkRequest`s. Is `QNetworkAccessManager` as single object the way to go? Documentation says there should only be one instance. So would I better use a singleton `QNetworkAccessManager`?

What would be the most appropriate way to go?

------ Edit -------

[kkoehne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33481194/356726) is correct from what I can tell. Also it is what documentation says. However, when trying this approach I have noticed 2 issues:

1. While we have now one `QNetworkAccessManager` per web service, changing to one single instance means I need to always distinguish what kind of content I just receive in the "finished" slot (the one called from `QNetworkAccessManager::finished`). That's feasible, but inconvenient.
2. We run our readers in different threads - I forgot to mention this in the question unfortunately. That makes it almost impossible to use a single instance of `QNetworkAccessManager`, as the member functions are [reentrant](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-reentrancy.html#reentrant), but not thread safe. ( [QNetworkAccessManager from ThreadPool](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5915771/356726) )

---

Related: [QNetworkAccessManager get/post from different thread possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35684123/356726)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're referring to `QNetworkAccessManager`, not `QNetworkManager`.

You should prefer having a single `QNetworkAccessManager` in your application. This not only gets rid of any need to synchronize `QNetworkCookieJar`'s, but also makes sure that the network is best utilized, and that cached content etc is shared.

As you noticed yourself, this is also hinted in the QtNetworkAccessManager  [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#details):

> One QNetworkAccessManager should be enough for the whole Qt
>   application.

Comment: correct, QNetworkAccessManager, not QNetworkManager my mistake. Fixed above

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and more importantly, doesn't work in multiple QThreads.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I have done (and which seems to work):

1. I could not use a single `QNetworkAccessManager` as we read in threads.
2. Sharing `QNetworkCookieJar` was not an option, as it is not threadsafe

But creating my own tiny threadsafe - derived from `QNetworkCookieJar` - class was easy. I only need to worry about the 5 virtual functions. This threadsafe cookie jar I can share among my `QNetworkAccessManager`s.

I run a certain risk here, as other public member functions of `QObject` are not threadsafe and could potentially crash, but these seem not to be utilized in that very use case.

Example code as requested:

```
/*!
 * Cookie manager, which allows thread safe sharing of cookies
 */
class BLACKCORE_EXPORT CCookieManager : public QNetworkCookieJar
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    //! Constructor, only allowed from BlackCore::CApplication
    CCookieManager(BlackMisc::Restricted<CApplication>, QObject *parent = nullptr);

    //! \copydoc QNetworkCookieJar::setCookiesFromUrl
    //! \threadsafe
    virtual bool setCookiesFromUrl(const QList<QNetworkCookie> &cookies, const QUrl &url) override;

    //! \copydoc QNetworkCookieJar::cookiesForUrl
    //! \threadsafe
    virtual QList<QNetworkCookie> cookiesForUrl(const QUrl &url) const override;

    //! Cookies for request
    //! \threadsafe
    QList<QNetworkCookie> cookiesForRequest(const QNetworkRequest &request) const;

    //! \copydoc QNetworkCookieJar::deleteCookie
    //! \threadsafe
    virtual bool deleteCookie(const QNetworkCookie &cookie) override;

    //! Delete all cookies
    //! \threadsafe
    void deleteAllCookies();

    //! \copydoc QNetworkCookieJar::insertCookie
    //! \threadsafe
    virtual bool insertCookie(const QNetworkCookie &cookie) override;

    //! \copydoc QNetworkCookieJar::updateCookie
    //! \threadsafe
    virtual bool updateCookie(const QNetworkCookie &cookie) override;

private:
    mutable QReadWriteLock m_lock { QReadWriteLock::Recursive };
};

CCookieManager::CCookieManager(BlackMisc::Restricted<CApplication>, QObject *parent) : QNetworkCookieJar(parent)
{
    // code
}

bool CCookieManager::setCookiesFromUrl(const QList<QNetworkCookie> &cookies, const QUrl &url)
{
    QWriteLocker l(&m_lock);
    return QNetworkCookieJar::setCookiesFromUrl(cookies, url);
}

QList<QNetworkCookie> CCookieManager::cookiesForUrl(const QUrl &url) const
{
    QReadLocker l(&m_lock);
    const QList<QNetworkCookie> cookies(QNetworkCookieJar::cookiesForUrl(url));
    return cookies;
}

QList<QNetworkCookie> CCookieManager::cookiesForRequest(const QNetworkRequest &request) const
{
    return cookiesForUrl(request.url());
}

bool CCookieManager::deleteCookie(const QNetworkCookie &cookie)
{
    QWriteLocker l(&m_lock);
    return QNetworkCookieJar::deleteCookie(cookie);
}

bool CCookieManager::insertCookie(const QNetworkCookie &cookie)
{
    QWriteLocker l(&m_lock);
    return QNetworkCookieJar::insertCookie(cookie);
}

bool CCookieManager::updateCookie(const QNetworkCookie &cookie)
{
    QWriteLocker l(&m_lock);
    return QNetworkCookieJar::updateCookie(cookie);
}

void CCookieManager::deleteAllCookies()
{
    QWriteLocker l(&m_lock);
    this->setAllCookies(QList<QNetworkCookie>());
}
```

Comment: Do you  have some example code of what you had to do to your derived cookie jar to make it thread safe? I know it's been 4 years, but it's worth a shot