# QNetworkAccessManager get/post from different thread possible?

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

I have a single `QNetworkAccessManager` object (as Qt docs recommend). However, I need to obtain a request from another thread, i.e. not the thread created the `QNetworkAccessManager` object.

This questions has two aspects:

1. As the functions (`get`, `post` ... ) are not marked `threadsafe` I assume that I need to use a lock before calling them.
2. But even if I make sure there are no 2 threads calling in parallel, issues could arise: So it could happen a `QObject` parent child relationship is set, but from objects in different threads. For that I would need to know the internals of `QNetworkAccessManager`

So is it allowed to call get/post from another thread?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is QNetworkAccessManager get/post calls from different threads
>   possible?

I found [QNetworkAccessManager from ThreadPool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915771/qnetworkaccessmanager-from-threadpool) discussed here some time ago.

And because [QNetworkAccessManager Class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) reference says:

> All functions in this class are reentrant.

And the reentrance explained in [Reentrancy and Thread-Safety](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-reentrancy.html):

> ... a class is said to be reentrant if its member functions can be
>   called safely from multiple threads, as long as each thread uses a
>   different instance of the class. The class is thread-safe if its
>   member functions can be called safely from multiple threads, even if
>   all the threads use the same instance of the class.

So, the answer to this original question is: for `QNetworkAccessManager` to be safe for multiple calls from different threads you need one class instance per thread.