# What is the proper way of opening a child dialog in a second thread in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread

I have an application where I run some process in a second thread and at some point, given a certain condition, another dialog window opens, which halts the process until you confirm something. This causes the following error message:

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QApplication(0x1f9c82383d0), parent's thread is QThread(0x1f9c7ade2a0), current thread is QThread(0x1f9c8358800)
```

Interestingly, if you also move your cursor over the `MainWindow` while the process is running, and before the new dialog pops up, it also produces this error message a couple of times:

```
QBasicTimer::stop: Failed. Possibly trying to stop from a different thread
```

Very strange. Because it *only* occurs if you move your cursor over the `MainWindow`.

Now, in my application, I actually load an interface for the new dialog that pops up using `PyQt5.uic.loadUi`, and this hasn't caused any problems. However, when I was creating the example for this post, another issue occurred, due to the fact that I was setting the layout of the new dialog during its initialization:

```
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
```

Which results in the application crashing:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong here regarding the threading I would guess, but I don't know what. I am especially baffled by the fact that I cannot set the layout of the new dialog during its initialization, while using `loadUi` is totally fine. Here is my example code:

```
import sys
import time
import numpy as np

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QDialog, QApplication, QPushButton, QGridLayout, QProgressBar, QLabel
)


class SpecialDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        btn = QPushButton('pass variable')
        btn.clicked.connect(self.accept)
        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(btn)
        # self.setLayout(layout)
        self.variable = np.random.randint(0, 100)


class Handler(QObject):
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)
    finished = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._isRunning = True
        self._success = False

    def run(self):
        result = None
        i = 0
        while i < 100 and self._isRunning:
            if i == 50:
                dialog = SpecialDialog()
                dialog.exec_()
                result = dialog.variable
            time.sleep(0.01)
            i += 1
            self.progress.emit(i)

        if i == 100:
            self._success = True
            self.finished.emit(result)

    def stop(self):
        self._isRunning = False


class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        btn = QPushButton('test')
        btn.clicked.connect(self.run_test)
        self.pbar = QProgressBar()
        self.resultLabel = QLabel('Result:')
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(btn)
        layout.addWidget(self.pbar)
        layout.addWidget(self.resultLabel)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.handler = None
        self.handler_thread = QThread()
        self.result = None

    def run_test(self):
        self.handler = Handler()
        self.handler.moveToThread(self.handler_thread)
        self.handler.progress.connect(self.progress)
        self.handler.finished.connect(self.finisher)
        self.handler_thread.started.connect(self.handler.run)
        self.handler_thread.start()

    def progress(self, val):
        self.pbar.setValue(val)

    def finisher(self, result):
        self.result = result
        self.resultLabel.setText(f'Result: {result}')
        self.pbar.setValue(0)
        self.handler.stop()
        self.handler.progress.disconnect(self.progress)
        self.handler.finished.disconnect(self.finisher)
        self.handler_thread.started.disconnect(self.handler.run)
        self.handler_thread.terminate()
        self.handler = None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = MainWindow()
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that I already found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50636079/how-to-prevent-the-qbasictimerstop-failed-warning-when-objects-become-threadl), which may be related to my problem, however, I don't undestand the reasoning of the solution in the top answer, and more importantly, I don't speak what I believe is C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create or modify a GUI element from a secondary thread and this is signaled by the error message.

You have to redesign the Handler class, with your requirement you must divide run into 2 methods, the first method will generate progress up to 50% where the GUI will open the dialogue, obtain the result and launch the second method.

```py
import sys
import time
import numpy as np
from functools import partial

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, QThread, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QDialog,
    QApplication,
    QPushButton,
    QGridLayout,
    QProgressBar,
    QLabel,
)


class SpecialDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        btn = QPushButton("pass variable")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.accept)
        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(btn)
        # self.setLayout(layout)
        self.variable = np.random.randint(0, 100)


class Handler(QObject):
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)
    finished = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._isRunning = True
        self._success = False

    @pyqtSlot()
    def task1(self):
        i = 0
        while i <= 50 and self._isRunning:
            time.sleep(0.01)
            i += 1
            self.progress.emit(i)

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def task2(self, result):
        i = 50
        while i < 100 and self._isRunning:
            time.sleep(0.01)
            i += 1
            self.progress.emit(i)

        if i == 100:
            self._success = True
            self.finished.emit(result)

    def stop(self):
        self._isRunning = False


class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        btn = QPushButton("test")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.run_test)
        self.pbar = QProgressBar()
        self.resultLabel = QLabel("Result:")
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(btn)
        layout.addWidget(self.pbar)
        layout.addWidget(self.resultLabel)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.handler = None
        self.handler_thread = QThread()
        self.result = None

    def run_test(self):
        self.handler = Handler()
        self.handler.moveToThread(self.handler_thread)
        self.handler.progress.connect(self.progress)
        self.handler.finished.connect(self.finisher)
        self.handler_thread.started.connect(self.handler.task1)
        self.handler_thread.start()

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def progress(self, val):
        self.pbar.setValue(val)
        if val == 50:
            dialog = SpecialDialog()
            dialog.exec_()
            result = dialog.variable
            wrapper = partial(self.handler.task2, result)
            QTimer.singleShot(0, wrapper)

    def finisher(self, result):
        self.result = result
        self.resultLabel.setText(f"Result: {result}")
        self.pbar.setValue(0)
        self.handler.stop()
        self.handler_thread.quit()
        self.handler_thread.wait()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = MainWindow()
    GUI.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This put me on the right path I hope. I guess I made the example a little bit too simple, because I actually don't know when exactly the condition to open the new dialog is met (and if at all), and how often this happens. But with your solution I came up with my own, although I am not sure how good this is. It would be great if you could take a look at my answer below.

Comment: @mapf 1) I only solve the problem they propose based on the code they provide, so I don't presume the complexity or modifications. If you had provided a better MRE, I would have proposed a more appropriate solution to your real problem. 2) Since my answer solves the problem that is in your question then I hope you mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it then check the [tour]

Comment: I understand, sorry. I wasn't aware of how relevant the simplification of my problem would be for the solution. It's a thin line to walk between including too much or leaving our relevant bits. Do you suggest I ask the same question again with a more complex MRE and close this one?

Comment: @mapf Yes, ask a new question with a valid MRE and also delete your answer as it is incorrect.